# Viewport overlays window doesn't change between object mode and edit mode

Tags: interface

the title says it all. I'm trying to follow a modeling tutorial, and I'm already stuck at the start of the process because the UI doesn't allow me to see what I should be seeing.
I just want to see the measurements part of the viewport overlays window, but it doesn't show.
[image: image of the edit mode Viewport overlays window showing the same UI than the one from object mode]
I'm on blender 4.01, if it can help.
Any ideas why?

Comment: Measurements are on the next icon, just on the right of the one you've clicked on in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

Since Blender 4 it's in the *Mesh Edit Mode Overlays* panel:

[image]

Comment: I love you man, thank you so much.